# Check if the Enter key has been pressed in the ngOnChanges lifeCycle hook?

Tags: angular, lifecycle, ngonchanges

I am running Angular 7.x - I have the following ngOnChanges lifeCycle hook and I need to determine if the user has pressed the [ENTER] key and if so pass this boolean value to the processLinks() below as a boolean value - what is the best way to do this as I am unsure of how this is done?

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
        console.log(changes);
        if(changes.text) {
            this.process();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a built in way of detecting enter key press

```
<input (keyup.enter)="testFun()">
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleChanges` describes only variables, existing in component.
To handle `'Enter'` key create handler in view for event '`keypress`' and check `keyCode` to be equal `'Enter'` key code

Answer (score 0):

You can use keypress event also like (keypress)="myFunction ($event) " in HTML

In TS File :

myFunction($event) {

Console.log($event.keycode) // here you will get the keycode of enter keyword.

If ( $ event.keycode == "13" ) {// just check it once whether it is 13 or not

this.process(): // whatever yours action perform from here

}
}